# How can I set my pages background image to the referring page's background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So this it it I've been trying all day to use javascript or jquery to set my page's background to the same background of whatever page is the referring url so far this is what I have

```
<script>
var xyz=document.referrer;
var urz=xyz.body.style.backgroundImage;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = urz;
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: This cannot work since `document.referrer` is a URI, not the referring document.

In theory, you could load that page (again) and do a lot of magic to obtain its background image. In general however (i.e. if the referrer can be any page), you won't be able to load it from Javascript anyway due to all kinds of security restrictions.

If in your use case you are in control of the referring page it is probably best to find a different solution to pass that information to the navigation target, but you would have to be more clear on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was hoping there was a way that would've been simpler, I guess I will stick to the simple things

For other people searching for this and have not a clue
if (document.referrer = 'url')document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img')";

Comment: Maybe clarify a bit better what your use case is. It can probably be solved more easily.

Comment: Oh I have two web pages, I'm an internet marketer and I have 60+ pages that all lead back to a next page on a next domain, I'd like to set the background of the final domain to which ever of the 60 pages the user is coming from, to have them feel a continuous theme kinda thing.

Comment: So it's not only the background image but actually the entire theme / CSS. So on each page, load your CSS ideally from a CDN, and in the link pass the theme name to the final domain through a query parameter or hash. Then decide on the final domain which CSS to load based on that information. And don't do evil to the Internet. :-)